# Android library reference cant find project.properties

Tags: cordova, apk-expansion-files

Inside my `root_folder/platform/android/project.properties`. I set the library reference like this:

```
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=${sdk.dir}/extras/google/play_licensing/library
android.library.reference.3=${sdk.dir}/extras/google/play_apk_expansion/downloader_library
android.library.reference.4=${sdk.dir}/extras/google/play_apk_expansion/zip_file
```

The SDK directory is correct. But when I try to build it. It shows an error : 
`.../sdk/extras/google/play_licensing/library resolve to a path with no project.properties file for project my_root_project_folder/platform/android`

Why this is happening ?